# onclick tag giving error in h:commandLink

Tags: jsp-tags, jsf-1.2

I'm using JSF 1.2 and I was trying to add onclick tag to h:commandLink which is throwing runtime error.
    The code I'm trying to write in jsp is:

```
<h:commandLink id="btn" styleClass="button" onclick="performAction();">
<h:outputText value="some value" />
</h:commandLink>
```

It is giving me an error:" Unable to locate tag attribute info for tag attribute onclick. "
Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [h:commandLink](http://www.developersbook.com/jsf/jsf-tags-reference/html/commandLink.php) it says...

> The commandLink tag renders an HTML "a" anchor element that acts like a form submit button when clicked.The commandLink tag is used to submit an action event to the application.

- Use `<h:commandLink>` tag to represent a link to POST form data.
- h:commandLink tag must include a nested outputText tag, which represents the text the user clicks to generate the event.
- The generated HTML uses  syntax.
- The commandLink tag will render JavaScript. If you use this tag, make sure your browser is JavaScript-enabled.
- The onclick attribute is automatically populated with Javascript to submit the form.
- Setting type = “reset” makes the link a reset button.
- Use the action attribute to associate the link with a JavaBean’s method.

You should check the source code via **view source** and check for java script errors via Firefox.